# Is there a way to keep ReSharper from formatting a region of code

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I use ReSharper's code cleanup all the time, but sometimes I have code formatted in a way that makes it easier to read than ReSharper's formatter makes it. Is there a way to mark part of your file with comments or something to make it skip formatting that portion.

(I'm not talking about inspections, I know how to have ReSharper ignore regions for inspections)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a discussion with Resharper support about this, their answer:

> Thank you very much for this information! We will discuss if we can
>   support such formatting style in one of the future versions.

Comment: Did they ever implement this feature?

Comment: @UweKeim I haven't looked into again, let us know if you find out anything.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, but you can try writing your own [Resharper plugin](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/open_api.html)

Answer (score 1):

As of writing this, you can actually do it the other way around. I.e., format only a selected area of code. Just select the desired block, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and type *Format Selection*. Meanwhile *Silent Code Cleanup* still cleans up the whole file. I agree, that a comment-styled exclusion would be very nice.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, now it is, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48683309/4454665) and [this feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-187963):

```
// @formatter:off
... Code you don't want formatted here ...
// @formatter:on
```

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer