# Freeze part of code against formatting

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Is there a way to lock or freeze a part of code against formatting in Visual Studio?

I want to protect the following code :

```
Method("This is a long text", 12 , true  );
Method("Hi",                  558, true  );
Method("Short text",          1  , false );
```

to be formatted as:

```
Method("This is a long text", 12, true);
Method("Hi", 558, true);
Method("Short text", 1, false);
```

but still be able to format the rest of the document.

Comment: do you mean when you for instance push `ctrl-k` `ctrl-f` for "format file" that you want to skip these lines?

Comment: It's no duplicate because I constantly use formatting. I don't want it off. Just want to freeze that part

Comment: @Default `ctrl-k` ← for bookmark `ctrl-f` ← for find/search

Comment: He means ctrl-k ctrl-d

Comment: As others have said - there's no built-in way of doing this. Additionally, since it is a very specific case, why not move that code into a separate Source_Unfmt.cs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn it off completely (`Options->TextEditor->Basic->General`) uncheck off Pretty Listing. And  under `Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting` turning off options there.

But, sadly, there isn't any built-in option to *selectively* prevent formatting a portion of code.

Comment: I doubt.. there must be a way to achieve that. Maybe not directly as a option but maybe some plugin do that

Comment: Even R# doesn't have a way to mark a selection do-not-format. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176429/is-there-a-way-to-mark-up-code-to-tell-resharper-not-to-format-it)

Answer (score 0):

The [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) formatting style, is the key for your problem.

Comment: Can you post link to some screenshot from formatted code by ReSharper ?

Comment: Resharper has LOTS of options for formatting. But not for protecting one section of code. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090354/is-there-a-way-to-keep-resharper-from-formatting-a-region-of-code)

Comment: it might be this feature will be added is in another version. we will wait `:)`