# Prevent ReSharper from formatting specific code block

Tags: resharper, resharper-9.2

Is there a way to prevent ReSharper from formatting a specific code block in a file? Something like:

```
void MyMethod ()
{
    // ReSharper disable formatting
    PRE     =   { my top format }   /* no rules */   ;
    // ReSharper enable formatting
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to keep ReSharper from formatting a region of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090354/is-there-a-way-to-keep-resharper-from-formatting-a-region-of-code)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible. See feature request [RSRP-187963](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-187963).

As a workaround, if you have a big chunk of "pre-formatted" code, you could move it to an own (partial class) file and add it to the "Generated Code" configuration list. This disables R#'s "Code Cleanup" for this file. Note that it also disables the inspections! (Unfortunately the "Generated Code Region" feature only disables the inspections, not the "Code Cleanup" for a region, as of R# version 9.2.)

Answer (score 41):

Now it is [possible](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Configure_Code_Formatting_Rules.html#using-comments-to-configure-formatter) in version 2017.3 like this:

```
// @formatter:off — disable formatter after this line
// @formatter:on — enable formatter after this line
```

Comment: Where should I put it? I have a file with dapper code, sql-source intermixed with function that uses it. I do not want code R# clean-up to move all sql-strings to the top of the file. Tried putting "// @formatter:off — disable formatter after this line" early in the file. No difference. Code-cleanup reorders everything.

Comment: @mattias Please ask JetBrains via their YouTrack issue tracker and report back how it's done for non-C# files : )

Comment: This did not work for me...?  I have R# 2019.2.1.  I use CTRL-K+CTRL-D to format my code.

Comment: @Jess Ctrl+K, D is the Visual Studio formatter. The above will only apply to Resharper.

Comment: It's unfortunately not working on XML (XSLT in my case) files, although HTML is supported per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Enforcing_Code_Formatting_Rules.html#using-comments-to-configure-formatter

Comment: The link is outdated; the current one (as of 2022) is [Use comments to configure formatter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Configure_Code_Formatting_Rules.html#using-comments-to-configure-formatter).

Comment: @Reyhn thks, i've updated link